# Boost converter extremely low efficiency

Tags: arduino, current, voltage-regulator, dc, boost

I'm trying to use a [boost converter from Pololu](https://www.pololu.com/product/2562) that steps up my 1.25 input voltage from a AAA battery to 5V in order to power an Arduino. I have found that my Arduino needs .03A to be powered.

I understand that if the boost converter were 100% efficient and when using `(V*I)in = (V*I)out`, I would need .12A to be drawn from my AAA battery into the boost converter. However, when measuring the current drawn directly from the battery using a multimeter, I find that 1.05A is leaving my battery and entering the boost converter, while .03A is leaving the boost converter and entering the Arduino. This implies that my boost converter is about 11% efficient. The voltage seems to be stepped up fine from 1.25V to 5V.

This efficiency is concerning since the Polulu component has an input current limit of 1.2A, and I also need to drive a small motor. I am wiring the positive and negative terminals of my AAA battery to "Vin" and "GRD" on the boost converter respectively, and then wiring the "Vout" and "GRD" pins to the "5V" and "GRD" pins respectively on my Arduino. I am not using the "SHDN" pin.

So, am I wiring the boost converter incorrectly, or is this efficiency typical?

Comment: It doesn't seem typical, at least.

Comment: That is concerning.  Besides the inefficiency, that 1 ampere drain will slurp a AAA cell empty pretty darn fast.

Comment: Polulu says it ought to have better than 55% efficiency at 1V input.

Comment: Are you sure, what you measured? You can still ask this question on Pololu, then ask for a refund if your finding holds true. Try to put two batteries in series. The remanent power should be transformed into a heat ,so thing should be pretty hot

Comment: I also tried this with a 2nd exact same 5V boost converter from Pololu and the exact same behavior happened. So this leads me to think it is my error somewhere. I am measuring amps by breaking the circuit on my breadboard, and then reforming it with my multimeter since current should then pass through the multimeter like a wire. The current readings everywhere else seem to be accurate, so I think I am measuring current correctly. I will try the two batteries in series right now.

Comment: Measure the voltage going into module.  If you have it wired through a breadboard then the contact resistance might be causing the voltage to drop.  Better yet, remove the breadboard from the equation.  Connect the bettery directly to the module and see if it gets better.

Comment: I will try this now, JRE. For batteries in series, I get .115A in and .044A out. Two batteries in series means a combined voltage of 2.5V, giving 76.5% efficiency. This seems much more reasonable, but for my application I can only use a single AAA battery.

Comment: I suggest you test the upconverter separately, connect battery to upconverter, leave the output of the upconverter **unconnected** (open) do you get 5 V at the output of the upconverter? Measure the current taken from the battery. If that's all OK, connect a load resistor at the output of the upconverter use 5 V / 30 mA = 170 ohm, 180 ohm or 2 x 100 ohm in series is close enough. Now almost 30 mA should be taken from the 5V. Is there still 5 V at the output of the upconverter?

Comment: Do realize that most Arduinos use a ATMega328 mcu which can run on a supply voltage of **only 1.8 V** but you might have to re-program the "brown out detection" setting for that to work. It depends on what the Arduino is controlling if you can actually go as low as 1.8 V, you're not showing a schematic so I cannot judge. You appear to want high efficiency and for that a lower voltage at the output of the upconverter will help.

Comment: The same results happened when I eliminated the breadboard. For Bimpelrekkie's comment, I just tested with the circuit open and got 5V at the output, and the current taken from the battery was 0A (I'm assuming that's what we want, since there is no load). Using a resistor for the load now, as per the second suggestion. And I didn't know that regarding 1.8V and the ATMega! I do have a component that needs 5V unfortunately.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, I just used a 100 ohm resistor (all I had), and got exactly .05A at the output! This verifies that output current is correct, since 5V / 100 ohm = .05A. However, .9A was leaving the battery (this should be a bit higher than .2A, so it is still drawing way too much current), and the output was 3.2V instead of the normal 5V with no load. Pololu says that voltage drops once the current limit is reached (1.2A), but the current limit wasn't reached yet since .9A < 1.2A. So, is there any explanation as to why this is happening? Thanks so much!

Comment: First you say there's 50 mA at the output with a 100 Ohm load then it's 3.2 V ??? Stop measuring currents for a moment and measure **voltages**. Are all voltages correct? Measure the battery voltage directly at the battery's contacts but also directly at the upconverter's connectors. Are you using only **soldered connections**? I suspect that  all your current measuring introduces a **voltage drop** (burden voltage) so that even if the battery is 1.5 V there could still be a much lower voltage at the input of the upconverter.

Comment: Remeasured all voltages- With no load, input voltage is 1.25V (not 1.5V since it is a rechargeable AAA battery) and output voltage is 5V. With the 100 ohm resistor as load, I get an input voltage across battery of .6V (haven't measured this before- shouldn't it stay at 1.25V? Why does it drop with load?) and output voltage of 3.2V. I do see that the output voltage is strange now, because ohm's law is now violated. Also, almost everything is connected through a breadboard with no soldered connections.

Comment: Boosting up to 5V from a single cell Alkaline or NiMH is quite difficult. Any little extra series resistance will make it much worse. Also note that under load, the battery voltage will always sag. I have been there and done that. If there is any way you can use two cells in series instead it will be quite a bit easier.

Comment: *I get an input voltage across battery of .6V* And there's your problem! *because ohm's law is now violated* Oh no it is not!!! Never assume that Ohm's Law is violated. It's **a Law** and only under very special circumstances does it not hold. You have **series resistances** everywhere: in the battery and all contacts on your breadboard. These resistances are preventing your setup to work as you want.

Comment: Great, thanks for all the feedback! I appreciate it. By 'violated' I just meant that something isn't adding up and I'm making a mistake somewhere, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the curves they published, What you are getting sounds somewhat close. I know you are losing voltage in the current measurement, that is the way they work.  The max with one volt in is 150mA at about 60% efficiency. I would assume you are below 1 volt which takes you completely off the curve. Consider putting two batteries in series, your efficiency will go up a lot and it might even work.